# Creating an Expect Script for Linux "adduser" command

Tags: linux, expect

I'm a newbie when it comes to Expect, and I thought that I'd get my feet wet by first trying out expect on my local machine.

To that end, I thought I'd try running Expect against the "adduser" command.

I can't get it to work properly, seems like everything is running properly, I am able to get to the last prompt, and it does exit, but the user remains uncreated.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn adduser testuser

expect "Enter new UNIX password"
send "testpassword\r"

expect "Retype new UNIX password"
send "testpassword\r"

expect "        Full Name []: "
send "\r"

expect "        Room Number []: "
send "\r"

expect "        Work Phone []: "
send "\r"

expect "        Home Phone []: "
send "\r"

expect "        Other []: "
send "\r"

expect "Is the information correct? \[Y/n\] "
send "\r"
```

Comment: add `expect eof` at the last.

Comment: Run your script with `expect -d scriptname` and read the debug output carefully: are all your patterns matching?

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as 'automateUser' ... chmod 775 ... and then on the command line.

sudo expect -d automateUser

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn adduser testuser

expect "Enter new UNIX password" { send "testpass\r" }
expect "Retype new UNIX password" { send "testpass\r" }
expect "Full Name" { send "\r" }
expect "Room Number" { send "\r" }
expect "Work Phone" { send "\r" }
expect "Home Phone" { send "\r" }
expect "Other" { send "\r" }
expect "correct?" { send "y\r" }

interact
```

If you type less /etc/passwd after, you should see your testuser in the list.

- adding the -d switch can make expect behave more predictably and it's great for debugging
- expect-s can be precise or loose (e.g. exact match vs 'contains')
- certain operations may require root ... like adduser

Tested against Ubuntu 16.04 with Expect version 5.45.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all these are wrong: `expect "        Something []: "`

I would use `expect -ex {Something []: }`

1. that uses "exact" matching since you don't need the power of glob or regex patterns, and
2. the braces ensure that the brackets are not interpreted as Tcl command substitution syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`expect "Is the information correct? \[Y/n\]` is ur problem.

Delete the [Y/n]

`expect "Is the information correct? send "y\r"`

You are missing the y or n in your code and you also get an error if you dont delete the Y/N.

I did it like this (with my Raspberry):

```
#!usr/bin/expect

spawn sudo adduser [lindex argv 0]

set password [lindex argv 1]

#depends what os ur are using

expect "xy something about new passwort:"

send "$password\r"

#depends what os ur are using

expect "blabla type it again blabla:"

send "$password\r"

expect "        Full Name []: "

send " \r"

expect "        Room Number []: "

send " \r"

expect "        Work Phone []: "

send " \r"

expect "        Home Phone []: "

send " \r"

expect "        Other []: "

send " \r"

expect "Is the information correct?"

send "y\r"
```

With this way you don't need to write your password into your script.

```
chmod +x 'yourscriptname'
```

```
execute 'yourscriptname' 'newusername' 'pwfornewuser'
```